# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Tags: python, selenium

estoy intentando crear un programa python con selenium, para que me automatice acciones en un navegador de Chrome.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep, strftime
from random import randint
import pandas as pd

chromedriver_path = r"C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\instabot-master\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path)

sleep(2)
webdriver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
sleep(8)

username = webdriver.find_element_by_name("username")
password = webdriver.find_element_by_name("password")

username.send_keys("")
password.send_keys("")
password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

sleep(3)

notnow = webdriver.find_elements_by_css_selector("body > div.RnEpo.Yx5HN > div > div > div.mt3GC > button.aOOlW.HoLwm")
notnow.click()
sleep(3)
```

La cuestión es que inicia sesión, pero necesito cerrar la pestaña que aparece y clicarla, pero parece ser que el comando .click() no funciona...

```
 File "botwebchrome.py", line 25, in <module>
    notnow.click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ten en cuenta que estás usando:

```
notnow = webdriver.find_elements_by_css_selector("...")
                               ^
                               ^
```

Dicho método **retorna una lista siempre** (`list`), por lo que realmente estás haciendo algo como `list().click()`, de ahí el error.

Tienes varias opciones:

### Solo hay un elemento en la página o solo te interesa el primero

En ese caso deberías usar `find_element_by_css_selector`:

```
notnow = webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector(
    "body > div.RnEpo.Yx5HN > div > div > div.mt3GC > button.aOOlW.HoLwm"
     )
notnow.click()
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que retorna una excepción `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException` si no se encuentra, deberías por tanto manejarla si es necesario.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

# ...

try:
    notnow = webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector(
        "body > div.RnEpo.Yx5HN > div > div > div.mt3GC > button.aOOlW.HoLwm"
         )
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("No se encontró....")
else:
    notnow.click()
```

Podrías usar `find_elements_by_css_selector` pero es menos eficiente y no tiene mucho sentido:

```
 notnows = webdriver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
     "body > div.RnEpo.Yx5HN > div > div > div.mt3GC > button.aOOlW.HoLwm"
      )
 if notnows:
    notnow = notnows[0] 
    notnow.click()
 else:
     print("No se encontró...")
```

### Hay varios elementos en la página y te interesan todos

En éste caso si debes usar `find_elements_by_css_selector` e iterar sobre la lista:

```
 notnows = webdriver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
     "body > div.RnEpo.Yx5HN > div > div > div.mt3GC > button.aOOlW.HoLwm"
      )
 for notnow in notnows:
     notnow.click()
```

Ten en cuenta que se retorna una lista vacía si no se encontró nada, en éste caso no hay excepción.

Pasa exactamente lo mismo con los demás métodos de selección:

- [Locating Elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)